# stop jquerycycle2 slider from jumping on load

Tags: jquery-cycle2

I have a slider made with the jquerycycle2 plugin, but it seems to initiate after the content has loaded causing all the images/content in the slider to show at once on first load. I don't want to put a fixed height with overflow hidden because the site is responsive and the height will vary. Any idea for a fix for this? Ideally I'd like to fade it in on load. You can see it [here](http://alexanderlloyd.info/puromenu/):

Answer (score 0):

```
.slideshow div {
    display: none;
}

.slideshow div:first-child {
    display: block;
}
```

This hides all but the first slide when the page first loads, and prevents the flash of content showing all slides before the jQuery kicks in.